# how to deal with this type image pixel work and change pixel color

Tags: javascript, html, image-processing, html5-canvas, pixel

I'm trying to change the text into one single pixel color like black and background to one single pixel color like white, i've used the code below but it converts only black and white

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    canvas {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <img id="originalImage" src="yourImage.jpg" style="display:none">
  <canvas id="bwImage"></canvas>
  <script>
    var originalImage = document.getElementById("originalImage");
    var bwImage = document.getElementById("bwImage");
    var ctx = bwImage.getContext("2d");

    originalImage.onload = function() {
      bwImage.width = originalImage.width;
      bwImage.height = originalImage.height;
      ctx.drawImage(originalImage, 0, 0);

      var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, bwImage.width, bwImage.height);
      var data = imageData.data;

      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 4) {
        var avg = (data[i] + data[i + 1] + data[i + 2]) / 3;
        data[i]     = avg; // red
        data[i + 1] = avg; // green
        data[i + 2] = avg; // blue
      }

      ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
    };
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

I'm trying to change the text into one single pixel color like black and background to one single pixel color like white

Comment: Someone is trying to break Captchas :) These things are designed so they are not easy to crack.

Comment: it's easy for those who have image processing knowledge

Comment: Well, I have such knowledge and I disagree.